# Get list of all possible 32 byte arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I'm trying to get an array that contains all the possible 32 byte long arrays. I should end up with something like this, where each subarray is holds 32 bytes

```
arr[0] = [0, 0 ...., 0, 0]
arr[1] = [0, 0 ...., 0, 1]
arr[2] = [0, 0 ...., 0, 2]
arr[255] = [0, 0 .... 0, 255]
arr[?] = [255, 195, .... 6, 3]
arr[n] = [255, 255, .... 255, 255]
```

There should be a way to do something like this with 3 for-loops right? I assume two of them would count to 255 and 32 respectively, but I'm not sure about the 3rd? Would it be all the number of all the possible arrays? How would one go about making a program that did this?

Also in terms of time, how long would it take to loop through all those arrays? I imagine quite a while since the number is probably really large, but I'm not sure just how large.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your three loops idea?

Comment: Well, you would end-up with 256 raised to 256 which is equal to 2 raised to 2048 subarrays! Is that right? Why do you want do to this?

Comment: @diogenesgg I believe you would have 256^32 number of arrays.

Comment: @PrestonM It's still a very large number to fit in any memory! it's in the order of 10 raised to 77!